# Camel File: SortBy modified

Tags: java, apache-camel, last-modified

I'm using the Camel File component with the sortBy:modified option.
The documentation at: http://camel.apache.org/file2.html
says:

> In the sample below we want to sort by last modified file, so we do:
>   sortBy=file:modified

but when I try to use it the first file processed is the "first modified", not the "last modified".
Am I doing anything wrong or is it just a small mistake in the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

To reverse the order you have to use

```
sortBy=reverse:file:modified
```

Comment: I know that, but do you agree the library works the opposite way of what it says in the documentation?

Comment: @Gep, I wouldn't say that it works the opposite. The documentation doesn't actually clearly state in what order the files will be sorted. `Last modified` is what the timestamp attribute of a file is called; it doesn't indicate whether the sort is ascending or descending. Just like `sortBy=file:name` goes from A-z last modified would list 2017-12-01 before 2018-01-01.

Comment: @Gep sorry, I didn't realise you were aware of that. But as noMad17 said, the documentation itself doesn't specify a default sort order.